# How to show or get the row data / values from a larger DataFrame using row indices from another smaller DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame (df2) that has columns of `Country/Region`, `Date`, `NewConfirmed`. I want to use the countries listed under its column of `Country/Region` and look about their data on another pandas DataFrame (df1) that has more rows. I tried the `merge` function but when I looked into the output csv file, various new columns where added with `_x` and `_y` concatenated on the previous columns' name like `Date_x` and `Date_y'.

I just want to get the list of the countries and their different values for each dates of newly confirmed cases so I can plot them later.

The data I used was a cleaned/transformed data coming from the Covid-19 datasets from John Hopkins University.

This is my df2 (with more rows) snippet:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
      <th>Country/Region</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>NewConfirmed</th>
      <th>index_by_country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Afghanistan</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Afghanistan</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Afghanistan</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Afghanistan</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Afghanistan</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Afghanistan</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-10</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>9.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-04</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-05</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-06</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-07</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-08</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-09</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-10</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>6.0</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>6.0</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>14.0</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>Algeria</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>13.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>Andorra</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>Andorra</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>Andorra</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>14.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-08</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-09</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-10</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>12.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>12.0</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>18.0</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>131</td>
      <td>130</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-25</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>132</td>
      <td>131</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-26</td>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>133</td>
      <td>132</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-27</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>134</td>
      <td>133</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-28</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>135</td>
      <td>134</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-29</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>136</td>
      <td>135</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-01</td>
      <td>6.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>137</td>
      <td>136</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-02</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>138</td>
      <td>137</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-03</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>139</td>
      <td>138</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-04</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>139</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-05</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>141</td>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-06</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>142</td>
      <td>141</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-07</td>
      <td>25.0</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>142</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-08</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-09</td>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-10</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>146</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>146</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>148</td>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>-6.0</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>149</td>
      <td>148</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>21.0</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>149</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>151</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>152</td>
      <td>151</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>14.0</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>153</td>
      <td>152</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>28.0</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>154</td>
      <td>153</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>22.0</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>155</td>
      <td>154</td>
      <td>Bangladesh</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>156</td>
      <td>155</td>
      <td>Bangladesh</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>157</td>
      <td>156</td>
      <td>Bangladesh</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>157</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>159</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>160</td>
      <td>159</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>161</td>
      <td>160</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>162</td>
      <td>161</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>9.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>163</td>
      <td>162</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>164</td>
      <td>163</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>165</td>
      <td>164</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my df1:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
      <th>index</th>
      <th>Country/Region</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>NewConfirmed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this was the output which has increased columns:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
      <th>Country/Region</th>
      <th>Date_x</th>
      <th>NewConfirmed_x</th>
      <th>index_by_country_x</th>
      <th>index</th>
      <th>Date_y</th>
      <th>NewConfirmed_y</th>
      <th>index_by_country_y</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-10</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>9.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Albania</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>11.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-25</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-26</td>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-27</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-28</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-02-29</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-01</td>
      <td>6.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-02</td>
      <td>2.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-03</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-04</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-05</td>
      <td>3.0</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-06</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-07</td>
      <td>25.0</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-08</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-09</td>
      <td>10.0</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-10</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>-6.0</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>21.0</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>4.0</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>14.0</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>28.0</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>22.0</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>2020-03-11</td>
      <td>85.0</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-12</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-14</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-15</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-16</td>
      <td>9.0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-17</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-18</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>2020-03-19</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>2020-03-13</td>
      <td>15.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rpanai, I already shown some snippets. Thanks for checking!